# Create new variable from another with condition (loop??)

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks (way more observations for days and uid though) like this:

```
   day   uid
1    1 0zOs6
2    2 0zOs6
3    3 0zOs6
4    4 0zOs6
5    1 3jtMi
6    2 3jtMi
7    3 3jtMi
8    1 5mJSn
9    2 5mJSn
10   3 5mJSn
11   1 dD8ro
12   2 dD8ro
```

I want to create a new, variable based on uid - basically a new id that starts at 1 and increases by 1 everytime we have a new id in the row uid, like this:

```
   day   uid newid
1    1 0zOs6     1
2    2 0zOs6     1
3    3 0zOs6     1
4    4 0zOs6     1
5    1 3jtMi     2
6    2 3jtMi     2
7    3 3jtMi     2
8    1 5mJSn     3
9    2 5mJSn     3
10   3 5mJSn     3
11   1 dD8ro     4
12   2 dD8ro     4
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `base R`, we can use `match` and it would be very fast and efficient.  There is no need for a loop

```
df1$newid <- with(df1, match(uid, unique(uid)))
```

Or use `factor` and coerce to `integer`

```
df1$newid <- with(df1, as.integer(factor(uid, levels = unique(uid))))
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option using `.GRP`

```
> setDT(df)[, newid := .GRP, uid][]
    day   uid newid
 1:   1 0zOs6     1
 2:   2 0zOs6     1
 3:   3 0zOs6     1
 4:   4 0zOs6     1
 5:   1 3jtMi     2
 6:   2 3jtMi     2
 7:   3 3jtMi     2
 8:   1 5mJSn     3
 9:   2 5mJSn     3
10:   3 5mJSn     3
11:   1 dD8ro     4
12:   2 dD8ro     4
```

or `rleid`

```
> setDT(df)[, newid := rleid(uid)][]
    day   uid newid
 1:   1 0zOs6     1
 2:   2 0zOs6     1
 3:   3 0zOs6     1
 4:   4 0zOs6     1
 5:   1 3jtMi     2
 6:   2 3jtMi     2
 7:   3 3jtMi     2
 8:   1 5mJSn     3
 9:   2 5mJSn     3
10:   3 5mJSn     3
11:   1 dD8ro     4
12:   2 dD8ro     4
```